# What is compiler flagging for numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, numbers, compiler-flags

What is compiler flagging for numbers in C#? What is the advantage of this work? I can't understand this concept.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Do you have an example of a compiler flag for numbers?

Comment: yes Henk, please write an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a compiler flag [`/checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf%28VS.80%29.aspx). It deals with numeric over and under flows.

Using it will cause a value outside the range of the data type to cause a run-time exception.